# Telling cakePHP to render as XML / use xml/blah.ctp instead of blah.ctp

Tags: php, xml, cakephp

I have been successfully using XML view files in CakePHP (request the XML output type in headers so CakePHP will use e.g. Orders/xml/create.ctp instead of Order/create.ctp).

However, now i need to add some functionality that requires me to the reformat the XML at the end of most business logic in the controller.

So i tried this in the controller action:

```
public function createorder() {
    $this->autoRender = false; // disable automatic content output
    $view = new View($this, false); // setup a new view

    { ... all kinds of controller logic ...}

    { ... usually i would be done here and the XML would be outputted, but the autorender will stop that from happening ... }

    { ... now i want the XML in a string so i can manipulate the xml ... }
   $view_output = $view->render('createorder'); // something like this

}
```

But what this gives me is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <response>
  <error>View file &amp;quot;/Users/test/Documents/hosts/mycakeapp/app/View/Orders/createorder.ctp&amp;quot; is missing.</error>
  <name>MissingViewException</name>
  <code>500</code>
  <url>/orders/createorder/</url>
 </response>
```

So i need to tell CakePHP to pickup the xml/createorder.ctp instead of createorder.ctp. How do i do this?

Cheers!

Comment: The trick is to use ``ext` => `xml`` in your URLs: `/controller/action.xml`. Then CakePHP along with the request helper component will all do that for you out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers refers to cakephp 2.4

```
I have been successfully using XML view files in CakePHP (request the XML output 
type in headers so CakePHP will use e.g. Orders/xml/create.ctp 
instead of Order/create.ctp).
```

In lib/Cake/View you can see different View files like:

```
View.php
XmlView.php //This extends View.php
JsonView.php //This extends View.php
```

So you told cakephp to use the XmlView. When you create a new View you need to use the XmlView instead of View. Or you can create your own custom View and put it inside app/View folder. In your custom View you can set your subdir.

```
<?php
App::uses('View', 'View');

class CustomView extends View {

    public $subDir = 'xml';

    public function __construct(Controller $controller = null) {
        parent::__construct($controller);
    }

    public function render($view = null, $layout = null) {
        return parent::render($view, $layout);
    }  
}
```

So what you need now is to create your custom view `$view = new CustomView($this, false);`

You can also write in your CustomView functions to handle the data as xml and use it to every action.

Also @Jelle Keizer answer should work. `$this->render('/xml/createorder');` points to `app/View/xml/createorder`. If you need this to point to `app/View/Order/xml/create` just use `$this->render('/Orders/xml/create');`.

Comment: Thanks this works. I need to add /Orders. Something i did not expect since i expected cake to pickup from the controllers view path (Order/) Also thanks to @JelleKeizer who was very close..

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->render('/xml/createorder');
```

Comment: Nope, this returns:"View file /Users/test/Documents/hosts/mycakeapp/app/View/xml/createorder.ctp is missing."

Comment: well make sure the template file is on that location

Comment: Please look at my comment, it says "app/VIEW/xml" and not "app/VIEW/ORDERS/xml". Cake removed the entire 'orders' bit so your suggestion can never work.